# How do I give a argument to a XSL Transformation?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm following [this article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/11/03/itunes.html?page=2) to get the contents of a iTunes playlist
The author says the following XSL can be used to transform a named iTunes playlist into M3U format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:param name="playlist" />

  <xsl:variable name="newline">
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="plist/dict/key[text()='Playlists']/
following-sibling::array/dict/key[text()='Name']/
following-sibling::string[text()=$playlist]/
following-sibling::key[text()='Playlist Items']/
following-sibling::array/dict">
      <xsl:call-template name="track">
        <xsl:with-param name="trackid" select=
"key[text()='Track ID']/following-sibling::integer" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="track">
    <xsl:param name="trackid" />
      <xsl:variable name="url" 
select="//plist/dict/key[text()='Tracks']/
following-sibling::dict/dict/key[text()='Track ID']/
following-sibling::integer[text()=$trackid]/../
key[text()='Location']/following-sibling::string" />
<xsl:value-of select="$url" /><xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I do that? From what I learned so far about XSL I thought I might have to replace *$playlist* with the the playlist's name. Am I right? And if yes, how can I do that efficiently as addition to the following code:

```
public String getPlaylist(String playlist) {
    Source source = new StreamSource(library);
    StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("M3Utransformation.xml"));
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    Result result = new StreamResult(w);
    try {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        return w.getBuffer().toString();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't [appear](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1495) you need arguments. What do you aim to do?

Comment: The author says it gets you **a named playlist** as M3U, so I don't know how to the the Transformer which playlist to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Transformer` has an API to pass in parameter values, you just need to add

```
transformer.setParameter("playlist", playlist);
```

immediately before the `transformer.transform(...)` line.

If you're going to be calling this method repeatedly then rather than loading and compiling the stylesheet every time it would be more efficient to load it once and then re-use the same `Transformer` for future calls:

```
private Transformer transformer = null;

public String getPlaylist(String playlist) {
    if(transformer == null) {
        StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("M3Utransformation.xml"));
        try {
            transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    Source source = new StreamSource(library);
    Result result = new StreamResult(w);
    try {
        transformer.setParameter("playlist", playlist);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        return w.getBuffer().toString();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

(Note that `Transformer` is not thread safe, so if you're making calls from multiple threads you'd need to use the `Templates` mechanism instead)

Comment: No, I'm calling this once after starting the program and work on with the M3U file. Thanks very much.